# Why does TypeScript have both `void` and `undefined`?

Tags: typescript, undefined, void

In TypeScript, you can annotate a function as returning `void`:

```
function fn1(): void {
  // OK
}

function fn2(): void {
  // Error
  return 3;
}
```

You can also annotate a function to return `undefined`:

```
function fn3(): undefined {
  // OK
  return;
}

function fn4(): undefined {
  // Error
  return 3;
}
```

So it seems that if you call a function returning `void`, you'll always get back the value `undefined`. Yet you can't write this code:

```
function fn5(): void {
}
let u: undefined = fn5(); // Error
```

Why isn't `void` just an alias for `undefined`? Does it need to exist at all?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

`void` has special meaning in function return types, and is not an alias for `undefined`. Thinking of it this way is *very* wrong. Why?

The intent of `void` is that a function's return value *will not be observed*. This is very different from *will be `undefined`*. It's important to have this distinction so that you can properly describe functions like `forEach`. Let's consider a freestanding version of `Array#forEach`, written with `undefined` instead of `void` in the callback return position:

```
declare function forEach<T>(arr: T[], callback: (el: T) => undefined): void;
```

If you tried to use this function:

```
let target: number[] = [];
forEach([1, 2, 3], el => target.push(el));
```

You'd get an error:

> Type "number" is not assignable to type "undefined"

This is a correct error - you said you wanted a function that returned the value `undefined`, but you actually provided a function that returned the value `number` because that's what `Array#push` returns!

Using `void` instead means that `forEach` promises not to use the return value, so it can be called with a callback that returns any value

```
declare function forEach<T>(arr: T[], callback: (el: T) => void): void;
let target: number[] = [];
// OK
forEach([1, 2, 3], el => target.push(el));
```

Why not just use `any` ? If you're actually the one implementing `forEach`, you really don't want that - having an `any` floating is a dangerous thing that can defeat typechecking very easily.

The corollary to this is that if you have some function expression whose return type is `void`, **you cannot say with any certainty that the result of invoking that function is `undefined`**.

## Again, `void` is *not* an alias for `undefined` and an expression of type `void` may have *any* value, not just `undefined`

In a function *body* whose return type is explicitly listed as `void`, TypeScript will stop you from "accidently" returning a value, even though this wouldn't create a type system violation. This is helpful for catching bugs that appear from a refactoring:

```
// Old version
function fn(arr: number[]): void {
  const arr1 = arr.map(x => {
    return 3;
  });
}

// New version
function fn(arr: number[]): void {
  for (const x of arr) {
    // Oops, meant to do something else
    return 3;
  };
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you! One question I still have is: why does TS allow assigning the return value of a void function if we shouldn't trust return values from void functions at all?
`function b(): void {}; const y = b()`

Comment: You can't really do anything with `y`, so there's no potential for problem as a result

Comment: How come it's different with arrow functions then, i.e:

`function foo(): () => void {
    return 2;
}` will error, while `const arrow_foo: () => void = () => 2;` will not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, and I now understand the intent better.
However, if `undefined` is how JS describes a lack of value assignment, then I still don't see any practical difference between `void` and `undefined`. 
e.g. `function noOp1() {}` and `function noOp2() { return undefined }` are equivalent to the calling code. The only possible scenario I could see a distinction being relevant is possibly with union types, but I'm still learning TS and can't say definitively yet.

Comment: As a corollary, does this mean that a callback that can optionally return some value (let's say a number) should be declared as returning `number | undefined` rather than `number | void`?

Comment: Then what is the difference between `void` and `unknown`? I thought the `unknown` type was the "anything in, nothing out" type? - which fits perfectly for function return types that are not observed.

Comment: Subtleties aside, `void` (TypeScript 0.8) predates `unknown` (TypeScript 3.0) by many years

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like TypeScript *sometimes* does treat void like undefined, which can lead to trouble: https://gist.github.com/rkjnsn/0435efb3af33d74b06d337f0f2706224

Comment: Given the JS runtime that this would compile to, this all feels too theoretical and borderline misleading.

Comment: Following up on André, why can we assign a `void` return value to an `any` variable? It seems wrong that we can do this: `const x: () => void = () => 42; console.log(x())`

Comment: @SWdV, because `any` is not just another type, it's "turn off type checking": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any

Comment: This SHOULD NOT be possible: `forEach([1, 2, 3], el => target.push(el));`. And it is not possible in modern type safe languages like Rust, because it is unclear for the caller what happens to the returning value.

In a type safe language it would be way better to force the user to write `forEach([1, 2, 3], el => { target.push(el); });` in favor of comprehensible code.

So, I vote against `void` (although it will not happen).

Comment: I feel what [ts 5.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#easier-implicit-returns-for-undefined-returning-functions) has added for undefined may just show that they realized that making the difference between void and undefined just don't worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

they are different in semantics.

- `undefined` means it doesn't exist. It's a negation of the existence.
- `void` means you cannot tell whether it exists. It's a negation of the discriminability of the existence.

---

Further thinking, below is the difference between readonly interface and functional interface.

```
interface RegularDictionary<K, V>
{
    get(key: K): V;
    set(key: K, value: V): void;
}

interface ReadonlyDictionary<K, V>
{
    get(key: K): V;
}

interface FunctionalDictionary<K, V>
{
    get(key: K): V;
    set: never;
}
```

In the `ReadonlyDictionary`, we don't know whether the method `set` exists. We shouldn't expect the data structure to stay unchanged forever, because it may be an instance of a class **which does have `set` but implements `ReadonlyDictionary`**.

This is why `ReadonlyDictionary` cannot be strictly used in functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void
[image]

`void` is not the same as `any`, nor the same as `undefined`.