# TypeScript - function that returns boolean passes as a void function

Tags: typescript

As in the example, if I have a type definition for a void function, a function that returns a boolean passes through that type check.

Is this is a bug or is there a valid reason for this? Is there a workaround?

```
type ReturnsVoid = () => void

type ReturnsNumber = () => number

const a: ReturnsVoid = () => { }

// Surprisingly there is no error
const b: ReturnsVoid = () => { return false; } 

// Error - expected
const c: ReturnsNumber = () => { return false; }

// Error - expected
const d: void = false;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true&ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AzgNQPYEsAmUAvFABQCURAfFAG654BQDoks8y6AcggLYBGEJEVIVC1FLwFImAYyzpgUAIYAuNolSZ6w8lSgBvKAF8mAelNQAysjBIcaHCgDmAGxBRgAC0HR7UFFhQgkhY0nIKUHxqcBro2Pg6otSGSOyoUABmSi5oEADcxlBmFgCiSCFCALRBAB6QMsAQjOFoijLRaVySgol6KZ2Z2bkFJgzmUGUVUNUQdRANTQwtinhqdAnEWTn5QA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does TypeScript have both \`void\` and \`undefined\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined)

Comment: Yes, sort of. According to that answer an expression that returns void can have any return value. It seems like the only solution is to not use expression types like this (and always define the return type in the function definition itself).

Comment: My use case was that I'm building a module using factory pattern and I wanted the functions in the factory match the interface definition. I solved this by using `ReturnType<MyInterface['functionName']>` as the return type in all function implementations.

Answer (score 2):

That's [intended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) behavior.

> Another way to think of this is that a void-returning callback type says "I'm not going to look at your return value, if one exists".

If it's an acceptible substitution in your case you may have a type returning undefined:

```ts
type ReturnsUndefined = () => undefined

type ReturnsNumber = () => number

const a: ReturnsUndefined = () => undefined

const b: ReturnsUndefined = () => { return false; } // error

const c: ReturnsNumber = () => { return false; } // error
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we0l1W)