# Is return needed in JavaScript functions that do not return anything

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I understand that `return` will both return some output a function may produce and stop the execution of that function.

My question is about those cases where the function doesn't return anything. It only performs something.

I primarily use JavaScript within the context of React and React Native so my examples are in React Native.

First example is a function that simply removes something from `AsyncStorage`. I typically use this when a user signs off. Do I need `return` in this case?

```
export const removeAuthData = async () => {
   return await AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth');
}
```

Another example is when I have a function that may update the state in my app:

```
setIsAuthenticated(value) {
   this.props.actions.setIsAuthenticated(value);
}
```

In these scenarios, do I need to use `return` in my functions?

Comment: Not if you're ignoring the return value. (Yes, there's always a return value, even if it's `undefined`.)

Comment: Citation: https://newbedev.com/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JavaScript is a weakly typed language, the return type and value of the function are entirely dependent on the value of the `return`.

Of course, if you don't plan on using the returned values of the functions, it doesn't matter whether you `return` it or not. Still, it may be a stylistic choice to `return` the last statement or not.

Lastly, if you `return` the result of an expression with value `undefined`, then it's completely indistinguishable, without looking at the body of the function, whether you actually returned or not.

TL;DR: Not needed, but up to stylistic choice and preference.

Answer (score 1):

No, in standard JavaScript, at the bottom of a function, if the return value isn't used;

- `return` is equivalent to
- `return <someExpressionWithoutSideEffects>`, which is equivalent to
- nothing at all (no return statement at the end)

Note that for those using TypeScript, things are a bit different - using the `return` keyword indicates that you really are trying to transfer a value from the function to its caller, in which case `return` or `return undefined` is [not quite the same as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined) lacking a `return` statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return a value from a function.
Note that functions do have a default return value which is `undefined`.