# Undefined not propagating as possible function return type, void works

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In a shared DB library written by a long-departed senior dev we have two helper functions

```js
/** Helper function to return *exactly* one result. */
export declare const one: <T>(a: T[]) => T;
/** Helper function to return zero or one result. */
export declare const first: <T>(a: T[]) => T | undefined;
```

The former works fine, but the `undefined` part of the union in the latter doesn't seem to work, instead being ignored by the type-checker when compiling. When we replace it with `void`, we see expected errors where there has been an assumption that it will return `<T>`.

I understand that there is a difference between `undefined` and `void` based on [Why does TypeScript have both `void` and `undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885485/why-does-typescript-have-both-void-and-undefined), since the function also throws errors when you replace the `undefined` with basically any other type, but `undefined` seems to be uniquely ignored.

This [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTBiFcDsGMBcEsD2kDOACWiMFMWwFwBQ0yeay2aAvGgDwAqAfABQCG+a9A2gLoCUHetUZpWXAAw9ipWGgBm8AE5kaDFu068BnNAB80UACbYFkbIeGiJUwiHq5Y01LNaLFrAJ4B5OQGVYivCQAOYoHHiBIbzUaFwA5AAW2AA2yYhxADRocQDuiIrJhpnZcojpWXEARq5xUiTOOHgAaqzJXmYxFGxunj7+kaF8TmSwDi3JoEoq8lOw3e7efgFBg4SEydiyESvj4NjhyyFohNshu5Q0o82t7ZR2CfDoKAmI4IVolZSs0NDYAA6jQxZHLYOIAN0opUUvws8FkmFEP3+LjQYNaexOh2C5xiV1g40mylkIE4DyeLzeFmwbnyWUq4Fkj0gcVk1MU+RWaCCaAAth40Ip-lgcklIFzGeh4Dy-vlAUA) shows the error, but I'm not seeing the error when the module is imported in my repo. Under what circumstances would the TS compiler ignore an `undefined` value in a union function return type?

Comment: I don't see an immediate problem. Can you demonstrate the TS error in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to happen in the playground, which means it's likely to do with an import. The declaration shows the signature correctly, though. Apologies if this is in fact a really tricky question, I thought it was just me doing something daft.

Comment: The playground link doesn't give me a sensible code example, I only see two lines. Also, you can configure your TS Config in the menu, maybe you can tinker with that?

Comment: Updated playground link with comments, and refined the question.

Comment: The link still isn't working :(

Comment: Updated again, don't know why that wasn't working. Sorry!

Comment: you probably have `strictNullChecks` set to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running your code in non-strict mode, which is fine, but maybe you're not aware of it.

In the playground you can uncheck all the strict options under TS Config > Type Checking and then I also see no error.

I would advise to turn on strict mode. Your project might suddenly give a lot of errors. Consider turning on the strict options one by one until you've migrated all your code.