# Why is the void implicit return type missing from my Typescript function?

Tags: typescript

Consider this function:

```
function foo(check: boolean){
  if(check){
    return 123;
  }
}
```

Why is the implicit return type only `number` rather than `number | void`?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jwy5xn?file=index.ts

Comment: Consider what would happen if `check` if falsey, and you don't `return 123`.

Comment: Are you using "strictNullChecks"? It's off by default. Typescript often ignores the possibility of things being undefined unless it's on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue here seems to be that you are not using [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictnullchecks), part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) that is more or less considered a "standard" set of type safety features and is strongly recommended.

With `--strictNullChecks` disabled, the values `null` and `undefined` are considered assignable to every other type, and get absorbed by them.  Any operation that could return, say, `number` or `undefined`, will be shown as returning just `number`.  Which is not great.

If you enable `--strictNullChecks` then you'll see that the return type of your function is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `number | undefined`, which would hopefully meet your needs.

(Note that `number | undefined` isn't *exactly* the same as `number | void`.  But the relationship between `void` and `undefined` is somewhat muddy and, I think, not directly related to why you only saw `number`, which I interpret as the real question. If you want to know more about that you can look at [Why is undefined assignable to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69728470/2887218) or [Why does TypeScript have both `void` and `undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885485/2887218) etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this is the key for me: '..the values null and undefined are considered assignable to every other type, Any operation that could return, say, number or undefined, will be shown as returning just number. '

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript, the implicit return type of a function is determined by the TypeScript compiler based on the actual code within the function body. In your example function `foo`, TypeScript infers the return type to be `number | undefined`, not `number | void`.

Here's why:

1. TypeScript's type inference takes into account the actual return statements in the function body. In your function, you have a conditional return statement `return 123;` inside an `if` block. TypeScript recognizes that the return statement is conditional and that if the condition is not met, the function may not return anything.
2. When a function doesn't have a `return` statement for all possible code paths, TypeScript infers the return type as `undefined`. This is because in JavaScript/TypeScript, if a function doesn't explicitly return a value, it's as if it returns `undefined`.
3. When you use the `if (check)` condition, TypeScript understands that if `check` is `false`, there is no explicit `return` statement. Therefore, it infers the return type as `number | undefined`.

If you want to be explicit about the return type including `void`, you can specify it explicitly in the function signature like this:

```js
function foo(check: boolean): number | void {
  if (check) {
    return 123;
  }
  // No return statement for the `else` case, which implies `void`.
}
```

In this modified function signature, you're explicitly stating that the function can return either a `number` or `void`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the detail but am accepting the other one due to the specific part I commented on.