# Why is a void type constructor param not optional, but the same is optional as a function/method params?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

[Typescript playground link:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6ATMALmAFzSIDcWOwA9gHYQEBOArsATUwBT5HSmIAlJhyjoBABYBLCADpeYaAF48hMJVEBfDFWwQApgQAiarnX0B3E0QGD0usZJny1y6OatqNObdoy0GAmgpQLA6YH03Dzh4ADcaKVxkLkFKEMYwiNkDY1NUjCA)

```js
class A<T> {
    data: T;
    constructor(data : T){
        this.data = data;
    }

    setData(newData: T) {
        this.data = newData;
    }
}

const instance = new A<void>();
//                           ^ Error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
instance.setData();
//               ^ no error
```

Here, the type parameter is set to `void` for the instance of class `A`. This sets both the constructor's `data` parameter and `setData`'s `newData` parameter to type `void`.

The constructor throws an error that `data` param is not optional, but `setData` works fine if you don't pass any value as an argument. Even though the type of the param is same, the behaviour seems to be different.

Why is this the case? How can I make constructor's param optional too, but only for void cases?

Comment: Which of your two questions is primary here?  Q. "Why is this the case?" A. It's a bug or design limitation of TS reported at [ms/TS#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131) Q. "How can I make...only for void cases?" A. Maybe [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mbyrdN) which makes any type accepting `undefined` optional.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining one of those in detail and the other only briefly, since SO posts [should ask a *single* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366).  Which, if any of those, should I write up?

Comment: @jcalz, actually I think the the issue link and your playground link perfectly answer my questions, thank you.
If you want to answer one of them, I think the "Why is this the case?" should be one, since that allows for the reason to be shared, and then users can implement their own solution using it

Answer (score 2):

[The `void` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) in TypeScript is *quirky*.  See [Why is undefined assignable to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69728470/2887218) and [Why does TypeScript have both `void` and `undefined`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885485/2887218) for example.

Here, you've run into the situation where a trailing function parameter of type `void` is usually considered to be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522), except that it doesn't work consistently with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  This is considered a bug, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131) and [microsoft/TypeScript#39600](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39600), but I don't see any indication that this will be fixed anytime soon, or ever.  At this point it's probably best to just consider it an unfortunate limitation.

---

In cases like this you might want to abandon `void` in favor of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that chooses between [tuple types for a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  A function of type `(x: X) => void` is equivalent to one of type `(...args: [x: X] => void)` and this latter form lets you write things like `(...args: [x: X] | [y?: Y] => void)` to give you more flexibility over whether the parameter is optional or not.  For your example it could look like

```
class A<T> {
    data: T;
    constructor(...[data]: undefined extends T ? [data?: T] : [data: T]) {
        this.data = data as T;
    }

    setData(...[newData]: undefined extends T ? [newData?: T] : [newData: T]) {
        this.data = newData as T;
    }
}
```

This checks whether or not `T` would accept `undefined`, and makes the parameter optional if so.  And it works like this:

```
const i = new A<undefined>(); // okay
i.setData("abc"); // error
i.setData(); // okay
i.setData(undefined); // okay

new A<string>(); // error;
const i2 = new A<string>("abc"); // okay
i2.setData(); // error
i2.setData("def"); // okay

new A<string | undefined>("abc"); // okay
const i3 = new A<string | undefined>(); // okay
i3.setData("abc"); // okay
i3.setData(); // okay
```

Here I haven't used `void` at all; `undefined` captures the meaning better and is less problematic than `void` (although you could use it if you want).  When `T` is `undefined`, you aren't required to pass arguments.  When `T` is `string`, you are.  And when `T` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | undefined`, it behaves like an optional `string` parameter.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6ATMALmAFzSIDcWOwA9gHYQEBOArsATUwBQB0fA2viIBdUizq4ApgDMAlnUm5okgB4FJEmImgB+aIMJgdpRMOikDRE8ICU6KjhwEAFrIg8hYaAF48h6JBklI4AvhgO0BCSBAAihrwCCgDucSJiEjLyispqGrhauvrJqUbW5kWSKYbWdpiOji5uHv6+xf6BFBFhYRi0DATQsj7QyXDw4lJyCrjIXDbk0AD0i9A0ANZgAJ4YsjxRsfEARGAARsCH80srkkxMnDt70SVzC8urG9u7+88TmdOXb3WW3CowQjCY8gA5rMAddbpxKH1GIMAEzDUHwcFQ2bHM4XV4rIGfFGPA5EF5XZTwpg7EnfI6TfGUokgypjLF0SHQAA+0F+U0UONO51h72BSIGsgAzOi2WDmFCeXyMgKZhTAR8dlLSc9cSKCWLPtr6eTRUSgA)

Answer (score 0):

The absence of a value is valid in the setData method because it is explicitly defined as an overloaded method with a signature that accepts no parameters. This allows you to call setData() without providing any arguments.

On the other hand, the constructor does not have an explicit overload that accepts no parameters. By default, a constructor without any parameters is expected to be called with the required arguments. If you want to make the constructor parameter optional, you need to define an overload that explicitly allows for the absence of a value.

When calling the setData method on the instance object without any arguments, the setData method is defined to accept a parameter of type `T`, which in this case is `void`. Since `void` represents the absence of a value, you are allowed to pass no arguments to the `setData` method.

To make the constructor parameter optional for only void types, you can use conditional types and function overloads.

```js
class A<T = void> {
  private data: T;

  constructor(data?: T) {
    this.data = data as T;
  }

  setData(data: T): void;
  setData(): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now, when creating an instance of A, you can omit the constructor argument for void types:

```js
const instance = new A<void>(); // No param needed
instance.setData(); // No param needed
```

And if you specify a non-void type argument, you will need to provide the parameter:

```js
const instance = new A<string>("Hello"); // Constructor param is required
instance.setData("World"); // Param is required
```

Comment: I somewhat understand the reasoning.
But your example does not work as expected. `new A<string>()` does not require an argument to be present. `data` ends up being set with `undefined` as the default value. [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6ATMALmAFzSIDcWOwA9gHYQEBOArsATUwBT5ED8pRAEpMOMdAIALAJYQAdLzDQAvHkJLIZSmIC+GKtggBTAgBF1XOkYDu5ooKHoD4qbIXqV0K7fXacevQxaBgJoaRCwOmAjT284eEYmcIBzZC4hSnDGSOi5YzMLDP0g8ChoACEkTwA3GmlcVFFoAAck6sIYxUFKKmDEtg5uRQEyRybsV3lFT2nNCipAwxM7MB51B1Ja+r98lfTNutwnMQB6E+g5S4WMQL7QrKIoo3LYmwqE5hS0ooec57zloVKEA)

Comment: What do you mean by "*explicitly defined as an overloaded method with a signature that accepts no parameters*"? I do not see any overloads for `setData` in the OP's code in their question

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned your class A with a constructor included a parameter. So you need to use an empty constructor or add the parameter when initialize it, or make it "really optional" by adding a question mark after the class, no matter what type you gave the class (error of the final line won't show because the wrongly you initialize the constant). See the example below:

```
class A<T> {
    data: T | undefined;
        
    constructor(data?: T){
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    setData(newData?: T) {
        this.data = newData;
    } 
}
const instance = new A<void>(); 
instance.setData();
```