# TypeScript `return;` vs `return undefined;`

Tags: typescript

I came across this (to me) weird behavior and I don't know if there is a good reason for it, as it doesn't make sense to me.

In typeScript if I do the following it works fine

```
type UndefinedFunction = () => undefined;

let uf: UndefinedFunction = function() {
    return; // no errors,
}
```

This makes sense to me, as in Javascript, when a function does a `return;` without a value, then the value returned is `undefined`.

But then if I do the following

```
type MaybeUndefinedFunction = () => string | undefined;

let muf: MaybeUndefinedFunction = function() {
    return; // error
}
```

Then I get the error `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'maybeUndefinedFunction'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'`

This does not make sense to me. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58885485/17537072) about void vs undefined, but it says that void is a way to indicate that the answer will not be observed. But why now `return;` is identified as `void` instead of `undefined`, if on the previews example it worked just fine?

If I do `return undefined;` the error goes away, but I want to understand why this is necesssary if `return;` and `return undefined;` produce the same result.

BTW, the same happens if I don't return anything at all; works on the first but not on the second event though both should comply with the `undefined` return value.

Here is a playground for you to see the error in action: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgOwCZQGYEsFSQMQK4IDGI6A9gjALwwAUAlFQHwwEoZZIDcwoksAsgEMwAIyiI2mbPiIlyVWg0rMAziABOmAOYwAPi2RopXHgBsoIFqgBc8Q+2kFiZCtVRO5CejADewGAEw6hZ46gjcAL5mFjAAtng2MEKi4vbGMs7ybh4u3n6BQSFhkTxAA

Comment: Return statements without a value are marked as "void". The void type is sort of like NaN. You aren't supposed to use something with the type `void`. It's treated like it could be anything.

Comment: You can also try this: 
  type stringOrVoidFunction = () => string | void;

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to adhere to naming conventions; user-defined types are generally in UpperCamelCase to distinguish them from user-defined values in LowerCamelCase.

Comment: @jcalz It was only for example purposes but you're right. I've updated the question with the standard naming conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically TypeScript would treat functions that don't return an explicit value as having [a `void` return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void) which means "nobody knows what this function returns" and not "this function returns `undefined`".  And before TypeScript 5.1 introduced [easier implicit returns for `undefined`-returning functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#easier-implicit-returns-for-undefined-returning-functions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#53607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53607), both of your examples would have resulted in errors:

```
let uf: UndefinedFunction = function () { return; } // error!
//  ~~ <-- Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'UndefinedFunction'.
```

[Playground link to code in TS 5.0.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgOwCZQGYEsFSQMQK4IDGI6A9gjALwwAUAlFQHwwEoZZIDcwoksAsgEMwAIyiI2mbPiIlyVWg0rMAziABOmAOYwAPi2RopXHgBsoIFqgBc8Q+2kFiZCtVRO5FejADeMdRZ46gicMAC+MAD0kTBQ6uqk6gCEwNEwMAB+GTAAPAC0eTAAKnwwAOTeyjAAbqToSGUw6CowCKSWgioq6FoIgiLmMCCkQ6VlEkYcMs7kZQB0wOaWALZ4NjBCouL2xtOeCu6yLoq+-oHBoWGpMZlZuQXFY5XMtfWNza3tMJ3dvf2Dw1G0HKmzEEwcuA8LnmPCAA)

But now, `uf` is not in error because, according to the aforementioned pull request:

> - Functions with an explicitly specified return type `undefined` aren't required to have return statements (similar to functions with an explicitly specified return type of `void` or `any`). **Note that this does not apply to functions with union return types that include `undefined`** [emphasis added].

But as you can see, this only works for function whose return types are just `undefined`, not [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) that include `undefined` like `string | undefined`. So `muf` continues to have an error:

```
let muf: MaybeUndefinedFunction = function () { return; }
//  ~~~ <-- Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'MaybeUndefinedFunction'.
```

---

That's the answer to the question as asked. Of course one might reasonably go on to ask *why* union types are not supported, and indeed there's a currently-unanswered [comment on microsoft/TypeScript#53607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53607#issuecomment-1575526070) to that effect. But it's not clear. Presumably supporting just `undefined` was an easy and conservative thing to implement and maybe they'd be amenable to a followup feature request asking for it to be expanded? But that's technically outside the scope of this question. The two cases you present are different because that's how microsoft/TypeScript#53607 was implemented.

Comment: That explains it, thank you so much. I got to think it was a TS bug or something. I still think it does not make sense as its inconsistent but now I know there is a reason for it. Thank you.

Comment: "*Why union types are not supported*" - I would guess "explicit is better than implicit" applies here. If you *always* return `undefined`, then `return;` (or even no `return` statement at all) is enough, but if you sometimes return something else you better write it out.